# Backup stored procedures for selected database and export to a textfile

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I developed an application where users can select specific tables to do backup and export to textfile for selected database and selected server.

My form contains a list of servers available within the network and on user selection of server corresponding databases will be displayed and when user selects the database then corresponding tables will be displayed and user can select the tables he want to do backup and when enters execute button it does all backup and exports to a text file.

Now I want to modify my program slightly when user selects database,if database contains stored procedures it should display list of all stored procedures in the selected database and should do the backup of them and export to a textfile.

Please give me any ideas to achieve this.

Comment: @Florian yes the database is sqlserver 2008

Comment: Ok. And what is your problem exactly ? Retrieve stored procedures from a database or export them to a filetext ?

Comment: @Florian  - Actually backup and write to textfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the SMO namespace which contains all you need to do that and much more

Add a reference to that namespace first

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;


      Server server = new Server(@[yourServer]);
      Database db = server.Databases[yourdatabase];
      List<SqlSmoObject> list = new List<SqlSmoObject>();
      DataTable dataTable = db.EnumObjects(DatabaseObjectTypes.StoredProcedure);
      foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
      {
         string sSchema = (string)row["Schema"];
         if (sSchema == "sys" || sSchema == "INFORMATION_SCHEMA")
            continue;
         StoredProcedure sp = (StoredProcedure)server.GetSmoObject(
            new Urn((string)row["Urn"]));
         if (!sp.IsSystemObject)
            list.Add(sp);
      }
      Scripter scripter = new Scripter();
      scripter.Server = server;
      scripter.Options.IncludeHeaders = true;
      scripter.Options.SchemaQualify = true;
      scripter.Options.ToFileOnly = true;
      scripter.Options.FileName = @"C:\fileName.sql";
      scripter.Script(list.ToArray());
```

more info at

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated